# laravel Validator::make

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo un problema con respecto a las validaciones, y es que no se como validar un arreglo:

```
[
0: {feature_id: "10", feature_value: 18}
1: {feature_id: "11", feature_value: "name"}
]
```

en:

```
private $featureOptions = [
    '10' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
    '11' => 'required'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
  $count = count($request->get('feature_value'));
  $feature_val=[];
  $feature_msg=[];
  for ($i=1; $i < $count; $i++) {
    array_push($feature_val,['feature_value'.$i =>'required|numeric|min:1']);
    array_push($feature_msg,['feature_value'.$i.".numeric" =>$request->get('feature_value')[$i].' debe ser un campo numerico']);
    array_push($feature_msg,['feature_value'.$i.".required" =>'debes enviar al menos un valor']);
    array_push($feature_msg,['feature_value'.$i.".min" =>'el minimo es de 1']);
  }


  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
    $feature_val,$feature_msg
  );
```